# MYSQL SUM row and GROUP by

Tags: php, mysql

Hi everyone and thanks in advance, 
I have a table with multiple products, price and quantity and I would like to add the quantity and group by product.

### Example

```
Description   Price  Quantity
Dojo hat      9.99   4
Dojo jeans    49.99  3
Dojo hat      9.99   4
Dojo jeans    49.99  1
Dojo t-shirt  19.99  2
Dojo hat      9.99   6
Dojo jeans    49.99  7
```

### and I want it to look like this.

```
Description   Price  Quantity
Dojo hat      9.99   15
Dojo jeans    49.99  14
Dojo t-shirt  19.99  9
```

---

**Here's my current code**

```
SELECT products.description, products.price, SUM(orders.quantity) AS 'quantity'
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id;

Description   Price  Quantity
Dojo hat      9.99   80
Dojo jeans    49.99  80
Dojo t-shirt  19.99  80
```

---

### Thanks again!

### Answer :)

```
SELECT products.description, products.price, sum(orders.quantity) AS 'quantity'
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.id = orders.products_id
GROUP BY products.id;
```

---

Comment: GROUP BY products.id, products.price ? what's the problem with your code?

Comment: How SUM of qty will look like this- 15,14,9? It would be like this - 14, 11, 2.

Comment: In SQL to do a aggregate like SUM you must list each not repeating column in the group by clause (Description, Price). You cannot just use the Id. Note for your case if there are two products with same description and different prices they ill produce two rows

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT products.description, 
       products.price, 
       SUM(orders.quantity) AS sum_quantity
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = products.id
GROUP BY products.description, products.price
```

Answer (score 0):

> Group By description and price

```
SELECT products.description, 
       products.price, 
       SUM(orders.quantity) AS 'quantity'
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN products
ON products.id = products.id
GROUP BY products.description,products.price;
```